# weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application:

Tags: java, webserver, weblogic, weblogic12c

When i am trying to run weblogic server 12c , it is throwing this error and is unable to start.

```
    <Apr 16, 2013 2:42:57 PM IST> <Warning> <HTTP> <BEA-101384> <WLServlet annotation is deprecated, please use servlet 3.0 annotation instead. App:acsportal@acs-portal.war, Class:oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsServlet>
    <Apr 16, 2013 2:42:58 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "acsportal" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application: acs-portal
    weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application: acs-portal
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:732)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:188)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:83)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace


Caused By: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '' is already in use by the module: / application: acs-portal

            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.validateContextPath(WebAppModule.java:1392)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:1238)
            at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:723)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:188)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:83)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

After this error, the server hanged at this point

```
<Apr 16, 2013 2:43:58 PM IST> <Warning> <WorkManager> <BEA-002919> <Unable to find a Work Manager with name wm/ProvisionWorkManager. Dispatch policy wm/ProvisionWorkManager will map to the default Work Manager for the application acs-portal>
```

and is not starting after this line
kindly help how to resolve this error.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bad deployment. Can you modify the config.xml file in your domain to remove the deployment? If you can get to the admin console does this help? http://dasutha.blogspot.com/2008/08/weblogicapplicationmoduleexception.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Stop the weblogic server
2. Remove all war files from the 'autodeploy' folder in weblogic.
3. Then start the weblogic server again
4. After that type the URL "http:// localhost:7001/console/" in browser
5. Go to " Configure applications" link
6. Then select previous projects and the go stop -> When work completes

Comment: I do not have any.war files in autodeplyo folder.so can u guess what would be the issue?

Comment: After that type the URL "http:// localhost:7001/console/" in browser
Go to " Configure applications" link
Then select previous projects and the go stop -> When work completes works for me.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to Weblogic's `config.xml`
2. Locate all `<app-deployment>` sections.
3. Delete them (you may want to backup it somewhere).

In my case it was more than thirty instances of our application:

```
<app-deployment>
    <name>deploy_ear_ear_exploded</name>
    <target>AdminServer</target>
    <module-type>ear</module-type>
    <source-path>*path_to_application*</source-path>
    <security-dd-model>DDOnly</security-dd-model>
  </app-deployment>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me works:

1) Uninstall all previous deployments (all ears)

2) Stop de server

3) Go to user_projects/domains/base_domain/servers/AdminServer/tmp and delete all content in this folder (you can back up the content)

4) Start and deploy

Answer (score 2):

1. Start the server
2. Go to deployments ( http://localhost:7001/console/console.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=AppDeploymentsControlPage )
3. Remove war deployments
4. Then restart, it should works

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with the following message :

```
Context path '/geff' is already in use by the module: /geff application: geff
```

I went to WebLogic Server --> Deployments. Here I had the 'geff' deployment. I deleted it, went into Eclipse --> 'Servers' view --> 'Add and Remove' on my server --> 'Add' the deployment I want.

And then it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

It happens to me because I manually deployed wls-cat.war in localhost:7001/console. But actually it's not necessary. When I tried to visit localhost:7001/wls-cat, weblogic is deploying wls-cat.war automatically. While the path '/wls-cat' has been occupied by the manually deployed wls-cat.war, it failed by the error:

> Problem occurred while dispatching servlet request.
>
> ......
>
> Caused By: weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path
> '/wls-cat' is already in use by the module: wls-cat.war application:
> wls-cat

To fix it, just delete the manually deployed one(s), and visit localhost:7001/wls-cat
Weblogic will deploy it.

So I suppose the main reason this error happens is the path has been used by another application. Check all the deployed applications in your console and delete them or change their package names.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the configuration wizard and recreate the Server. For the integrated server I deleted the whole DefaultDomain folder and JDeveloper recreate the Web Server again.

Answer (score 0):

use command: **docker system prune**
Than just build and run all the containers again