# Weblogic 12.1.3 context path already in use by the module error

Tags: java, deployment, webserver, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am facing an annoying `Weblogic` problem. Here is the history:

1. We were using `Weblogic 12.1.1` (Test env.) and deployment was working fine
2. I made a deployment and it didn't work. Our solution required at least v12.1.2 and therefore I uninstalled 12.1.1 and installed `Weblogic 12.1.3`
3. Before installing the new version, I completely deleted `u01` folder and created back from scratch
4. I installed Weblogic 12.1.3 in silent mode and created my test domain. There are only admin server and one single stand-alone managed server in the domain (no clusters, no numeraous managed servers)
5. I made the deployment but Weblogic keeps givinig me `"Error weblogic.application.ModuleException: Context path '/edys-web' is already in use by the module: edys-web application: edys-web-test"` error
6. I followed instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033609/weblogic-application-moduleexception-context-path-is-already-in-use-by-the-m) but I had no luck (BTW, either there is no Application Configuraion in Weblogic 12.1.3 console or I failed to find the link)

Now, I don't what else to do. There is not much information on the Internet. How can I solve this problem?

PS: The same application works fine in other Weblogic 12.1.3 environments.

Edit 1: I am adding my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<domain xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain" xmlns:sec="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/wls/1.0/wls.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/domain http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/domain.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml/1.0/xacml.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator/1.0/passwordvalidator.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/1.0/security.xsd">
  <name>oraworld_domain</name>
  <domain-version>12.1.3.0.0</domain-version>
  <security-configuration>
    <name>oraworld_domain</name>
    <realm>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-authenticatorType">
        <sec:name>DefaultAuthenticator</sec:name>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:authentication-provider xsi:type="wls:default-identity-asserterType">
        <sec:name>DefaultIdentityAsserter</sec:name>
        <sec:active-type>AuthenticatedUser</sec:active-type>
      </sec:authentication-provider>
      <sec:role-mapper xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-role-mapperType">
        <sec:name>XACMLRoleMapper</sec:name>
      </sec:role-mapper>
      <sec:authorizer xmlns:xac="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/xacml" xsi:type="xac:xacml-authorizerType">
        <sec:name>XACMLAuthorizer</sec:name>
      </sec:authorizer>
      <sec:adjudicator xsi:type="wls:default-adjudicatorType">
        <sec:name>DefaultAdjudicator</sec:name>
      </sec:adjudicator>
      <sec:credential-mapper xsi:type="wls:default-credential-mapperType">
        <sec:name>DefaultCredentialMapper</sec:name>
      </sec:credential-mapper>
      <sec:cert-path-provider xsi:type="wls:web-logic-cert-path-providerType">
        <sec:name>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:name>
      </sec:cert-path-provider>
      <sec:cert-path-builder>WebLogicCertPathProvider</sec:cert-path-builder>
      <sec:name>myrealm</sec:name>
      <sec:password-validator xmlns:pas="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/security/providers/passwordvalidator" xsi:type="pas:system-password-validatorType">
        <sec:name>SystemPasswordValidator</sec:name>
        <pas:min-password-length>8</pas:min-password-length>
        <pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>1</pas:min-numeric-or-special-characters>
      </sec:password-validator>
    </realm>
    <default-realm>myrealm</default-realm>
    <credential-encrypted>{AES}XqD6eClO7wwKxv5mZUZC0PpR06elab9QCYfO9eovVjAWFIyvGlP/uYwcUZ+hNjeEpldGjr1PZABBKWSx5ZFlKSzUCkNr33T5YgdnZ1FC1fKaKGI/DG5iVuWNgHtb78Yt</credential-encrypted>
    <node-manager-username>weblogic</node-manager-username>
    <node-manager-password-encrypted>{AES}tA8QqN18hJTix40QCKTzl9DeqeKXx8qBWdVRU402Z7I=</node-manager-password-encrypted>
  </security-configuration>
  <server>
    <name>AdminServer</name>
    <ssl>
      <name>AdminServer</name>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
    </ssl>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
  </server>
  <server>
    <name>edys-web</name>
    <listen-port>8200</listen-port>
    <web-server>
      <web-server-log>
        <number-of-files-limited>false</number-of-files-limited>
      </web-server-log>
    </web-server>
    <listen-address></listen-address>
  </server>
  <embedded-ldap>
    <name>oraworld_domain</name>
    <credential-encrypted>{AES}VymYmNOZJKNXuopmGNayCRADs+iKI6Y/G1lG27Axik5eDs0wWfvrsak/eVXsq2Ja</credential-encrypted>
  </embedded-ldap>
  <configuration-version>12.1.3.0.0</configuration-version>
  <machine>
    <name>Machine-1</name>
  </machine>
  <admin-server-name>AdminServer</admin-server-name>
</domain>
```

Edit 2: I am adding weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>12.1.3</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>edys-web</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
<!--        <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes> -->
         <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.hql.ast.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.faces.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:package-name>
                        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
                        <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javassist</wls:package-name>
                        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
     </wls:prefer-application-packages>


<wls:prefer-application-resources>
   <wls:resource-name>javax.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
      <wls:resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
         <wls:resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</wls:resource-name>

<wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</wls:resource-name>
<wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</wls:resource-name>
<resource-name>META-INF/validation-mapping-1.1.xsd</resource-name>
        <resource-name>META-INF/validation-configuration-1.1.xsd</resource-name>
   </wls:prefer-application-resources>


    <wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</wls:show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Comment: Do you see the application in your WebLogic config.xml before you try to deploy?

Comment: @BrianOchs No, I didn't. Where can I find the xml file and what should I check in the file? BTW, since this is a clean installation, why do you think there is something in the config.xml file?

Comment: There is a /config folder under the domain folder with the config.xml. There is a section in this file that shows all of the currently installed applications.

Comment: @BrianOchs I have editid my post to include the content of the config.xml but as you can see there is only one "edys-web" server and I created it. It still doesn't make sense to have this error since there is only one edys-web server

Comment: Are you deploying via the autodeploy folder or via the console?

Comment: @BrianOchs No, I am not using autodeploy folder. The folder is empty. I am unpacking my war files into folders and then deploying them through admin server (The server deployment staging model is no-stage). I have deleted files under folders such as autodeploy, tmp, data etc. but still no luck with the deployment.

Comment: Are you trying to deploy a single EAR with multiple WARs? Do you have the context root specified in weblogic.xml files?

Comment: @BrianOchs I am trying to deploy a single war file into a single stand-alone server and context root is specified in weblogic.xml file.  Even in my first attempt, Weblogic says the context-root is already in use (and the server using the context root is the server I am trying to deploy)

Comment: @BrianOchs A side note; I have installed Weblogic into a brand new virtual machine and the problem continues. There is something wrong with my configuration but I cannot figure what it is

Comment: Will it deploy if you use the autodeploy folder? That will rule out anything wrong with the WAR build. What does your weblogic.xml file have in it?

Comment: @BrianOchs I haven't tried autodeploy yet because I don't know how it works. Will I just drop the war file into the folder? Then how will Weblogic know what server to deploy? I added my weblogic.xml into my post.

Comment: Right, just drop the WAR file in the autodeploy folder and WebLogic will automatically deploy. Watch the server logs for the deployment to happen watching for any errors.

Comment: @BrianOchs Sorry for dumb questions but into which server will Weblogic deploy my war file? I dropped my war file and restarted Weblogic but which log files should I follow?

Comment: @BrianOchs Either nothing happened or I did something wrong. I dropped the war file into autodeploy folder and restarted Weblogic. However, there is nothing in both Deployments tab and AdminServer/Deployments. I also cannot access it through the admin server's port. I am getting tired of this. This shouldn't be this hard or at least tell me what is wrong. I have been struggling with this for 3 days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81679/discussion-between-brian-ochs-and-iso-9001).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out at last. First, I was looking at wrong logs, the problem wasn't the context root but it was about Weblogic which wasn't able to find Hibernate Validator. This a bug and Oracle released an Interim patch (20087183) for this bug. After I applied the patch, the problem was solved.